# Process to Attach Initiation Infopath2010 Form with Sequential Workflow

Tags: workflow, infopath, initiation-form

Here I want Infopath2010 form will appear when I want to start manual Sequential Workflow in visual studio2010.For that I am using Initiation Form(created in Infopath2010) Process. DO anybody have any idea What is the process to attach Infopath form with sequential workflow in visual studio2010

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've wrote step-by-step tutorial how to do this. Check it out [here](http://spblog.net/post/2012/03/07/Creating-InfoPath-association-%28or-instantiation%29-form-for-SharePoint-2010-Visual-Studio-workflow.aspx) and feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thanx Kai.....But I am facing System.ArgumentNullException Do you have any Idea How canI solve this

Comment: @ashishjoshi, please provide more details about where and how this exception is occurred, stack trace if presented

Comment: public static SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();
        static XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AssociationParameters));
        
static XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(workflowProperties.InitiationData));
        AssociationParameters initform = (AssociationParameters)serializer.Deserialize(reader);  Here at Stringreader it gives Excepti

Comment: `workflowProperties.InitiationData` is null for you. Do initiation form appear, when you start workflow on item? Do you specify `InstantiationUrl` in elements.xml for workflow? When you associate your workflow to a list, checkbox "Start this workflow when a new item is created." should be **unchecked**. I've just verified my project with initiation form - I changed `AssociationUrl` to `InstantiationUrl="_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx"`, replaced `AssociationFormURN` with `InstantiationFormURN`, added workflowProperties.InitiationData (instead of AssociationData) in code and all work fine.

Comment: I did all the things Properly  but It is given erro at the time I Build my sequential Workflow.

Comment: Hey If I am Trying your code then I find error for XmlSerializationHelper does not exist in Current Context. Can you tell Where you relate It ?

Comment: I've uploaded version with initiation form, refresh post and try it out.

Comment: XmlSerializationHelper declared in the same project

Comment: Can you tell me where should I declare this ? Because I am not declared it.

Comment: class definition you can find in my project

Comment: Thanx Kai Now my Solution Build Successfully but It Gives Error :Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Failed to create receiver object from assembly "Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", class "“Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver"" for feature "leavEmailCustWorkflow_Feature1" (ID: c6749a77-0183-4479-8054-a7d596a17d33).: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Do You Have Any Idea About It

Comment: Thanx a lot....finally it is running successfully

Comment: Do you have sharepoint enterprise installed? Check if this dll (Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature) are in the GAC